# Mocha testing a bluebird powered node style callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, bluebird

I am facing trouble to get pass a test by running `mocha` which seems to be passing.

The test:

```
describe('.get()',function() {

    it('should be called once',function() {
        // => Need to spy on this
        var callback = function(err,data) {
            console.log('I am called');
            if (err) {
                console.log('I am logging the error '+err);
            } else {
                console.log('I am logging the data '+data);
            }
        }

        agentMock._response = {body:'something',headers:'headers'};

        // => Start Spying
        var spy = sinon.spy(callback);
        sinon.spy(agentMock,'get');

        baseRequest.get(spy); // refer (a) below

        expect(agentMock.get).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        expect(spy).to.have.been.calledWith(null,'data');
    });
});
```

I want to test whether the `callback` is called or not. Therefore, I logged in the body of the callback, and the stdout also suggests it's being called.

The stdout :

```
  .get()
    1) should be called once
I am called
I am logging the data something


  0 passing (15ms)
  1 failing

  1) .get() should be called once:
     AssertionError: expected spy to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times
```

**Details:**

(a) `baseRequest.get` return the data as a `bluebird` promise. This can be used by passing in a `nodeback` to `.get` itself or by chaining `.then` after `.get` call.

```
BaseRequest.prototype.get = function(callback) {
    // inner details

    return invokeandPromisify(request,callback);
}

function invokeandPromisify(request, callback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    // Invoke the request
    request.end(function(err,result) {

        // Return the results as a promise
        if (err || result.error) {
            reject(err || result.error);
        } else {
            resolve(result);
        }
    });
    }).nodeify(callback); // to have a node style callback
}
```

Does it happen because the **callback** on which I want to **spy** is passed to a different function( `invokeandPromisify` here ) and the spying is lost ? I am just interpreting this.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `baseRequest#get` returns a promise, I would make the assertions after the promise is resolved.

See example below:

```
it('should be called once',function(done) {
    // => Need to spy on this
    var callback = function(err,data) {
        console.log('I am called');
        if (err) {
            console.log('I am logging the error '+err);
        } else {
            console.log('I am logging the data '+data);
        }
    }

    agentMock._response = {body:'something',headers:'headers'};

    // => Start Spying
    var spy = sinon.spy(callback);
    sinon.spy(agentMock,'get');

    baseRequest.get(spy).finally(function() {
      expect(agentMock.get).to.have.been.calledOnce;
      expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
      expect(spy).to.have.been.calledWith(null,'data');
      done();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, saved my day ! Can you elaborate a bit more what is the issue here as I am already setting the response by setting the value of `agentMock._response`.

Comment: Is not a synchronous test after that ? I am not getting it.

Comment: Promises are async, so your test had to be async as well. I used `#finally` to ensure the assertions were made when the promise was resolved, then called `done()` to signal the end of the async test.

Comment: Yeah, finally got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your test should be set as async by adding done. Then in your callback funtion call done()

Please check http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: `agentMock._response = {body:'something',headers:'headers'};` sets the response immediately. So, is it async now ?